# Spring: How to load @ContextConfiguration from jar classpath? I get FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring

I have a project called `X` which has `wireup.xml` laid as follows :

```
X/
 Module/
       src/
           main/
               resources/
                        com.here/
                                wireup.xml
```

I import `Module` of `project X` in `project Y` as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.X</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module</artifactId>
        <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now in the test I want bean that is in `wireup.xml`, so I do the following :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:com/org/X/Module/src/main/resources/com/here/wireup.xml"})
public class MongoSaverTest extends Case {
  @Autowired
  private SomeBeanInWireup variable;
}
```

But I get error on running the test saying

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/org/X/Module/src/main/resources/com/here/wireup.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How can I fix this? How can I know the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just be `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:com/here/wireup.xml"})`

Answer (score 0):

The path for your resource is `classpath:com/here/wireup.xml`